# O que significa <T> em .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e vi muito código como este

```
public class ExemploCollection<T> { ... }
```

E eu não entendo o que este `<T>` significa.

Qual é o nome disso, pelo que procuro? Como que isso funciona? O que isso faz?

Comment: Acho pouco honesto remover uma postagem por receber votos contra e repostá-las depois. Acho legal tentar manter a seriedade da comu.

Comment: @Don para ser justo, a qualidade da pergunta nessa repostagem é muito superior à da primeira postagem (em outras palavras, agora está uma pergunta verossímil, enquanto a anterior parecia ter sido feita com objetivo exclusivo de justificar a resposta)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Nesse caso talvez fosse melhor editar a postagem, não quero me estender mais no assunto, foi apenas a minha visão pessoal.

Comment: @Don Já eu sou indiferente entre editar ou apagar/repostar. A única coisa que importa pra mim é a qualidade da última revisão. Afinal, quem votou contra votou na publicação de má qualidade, e nem todos reavaliarão o voto após a edição. Ter uma publicação de qualidade boa/razoável carregando o "legado" de uma de má qualidade não beneficia ninguém, IMHO.

Comment: Essa pergunta foi feita somente para postar a resposta logo em seguida? Ou o SO tá com bug e mostra a mesma pessoa e resposta no mesmo minuto?

Comment: Concordo parcialmente com os 2, na teoria deveria atualizar a pergunta para melhorar-la, mas sabemos que na prática não funciona bem assim, os votos negativos não serão revistos, e a pergunta pertinente será desprezada.

Comment: @MayogaX isso é ok, e até incentivado. Veja mais em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O nome do contexto disso é *Generics*, [veja a documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

`T` não é uma palavra reservada. `T`, ou qualquer outro nome dado, significa "parâmetro de tipo". Veja o seguinte método:

```cs
T GetDefault<T>()
{
    return default(T);
}
```

Note que o **tipo** de retorno do método é `T`. Com este método eu posso pegar o valor padrão de qualquer tipo desta forma:

```cs
GetDefault<int>(); // 0
GetDefault<string>(); // null
GetDefault<DateTime>(); // 01/01/0001 00:00:00
GetDefault<TimeSpan>(); // 00:00:00
```

O .NET utiliza *generics* em coleções de objetos, exemplo com `List<T>`

```cs
List<int> listaDeInteiros = new List<int>();
```

Desta forma você terá uma lista que só irá aceitar inteiros, pois a classe é instanciada com o tipo "T", neste caso `int` e o método que adiciona elementos só aceita o tipo informado na hora de instanciar a classe:

```cs
public class List<T> : ...
{
    public void Add(T item);
}
```

Como nós temos um `List<int>`, o método `Add` só irá aceitar inteiros.

Em *generics* é possivel limitar o escopo do tipo `T`.

O seguinte exemplo só permite o uso do método com tipos que são classes

```cs
void FazAlgo<T>(T item) where T: class
{
}
```

O seguinte exemplo só permite o uso do método com tipos que são classes do tipo `Circulo` ou que herdem de `Circulo`.

```cs
void FazAlgo<T>(T item) where T: Circulo
{
}
```

E também existe o `new()`, que se usado desta forma, pode-se criar uma instancia de circulo:

```cs
void FazAlgo<T>(T item) where T: Circulo, new()
{
    T novoCirculo = new T();
}
```

Como `T` é um parâmetro de tipo, é possível obter o objeto `Type`. E com o objeto `Type` é possível fazer diversas coisas utilizando *reflection*.

```cs
void FazAlgo<T>(T item) where T: class
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
}
```

---

Em um exemplo mais complexo, para demonstrar o que é possível fazer com *generics* veja a declaração do método `ToDictionary`, ou qualquer outro método do Linq.

```cs
public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);
```

Veja que não há o `T`. Como disse anteriormente `T` não é uma palavra reservada. É sempre uma pratica nomear os parâmetros de tipo com o prefixo `T`, como visto no exemplo acima `TKey` e `TSource`.

Você pode nomear `TFoo` se quiser.